# Banner ad not showing after app store application update

Tags: android, admob

Initially, my application was showing ads but recently I have updated my application on play store after which it is not showing banner ads most of the times but Interstitial ads are being shown.

After checking the logcat it shows "Ad failed to load : 3" which normally occurs initially when you release your apps/ads initially.

Below is the code:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/first_banner"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

There is nothing wrong with your code , the issue is admob doesnt always have Ad to return for your request possible reasons could be

-you have just registered your publisher id as it takes some time to start serving ads

-you have filtered some ads

Kindly refer this doc: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL